# How to save values in editable gridview?

Tags: gridview

I have an editable gridview with blank cells. User enters some numeric data in cells and also user can clicks a button to add new row to gridview. My problem is that, as soon as button click event is fired, the page refreshes & the gridview becomes empty. Can anybody tell me, how can I save values in gridview until the user saves all changes to the server in the end

Comment: can you show some code 1) how do you load the grid 2) what's under the "Add" button

Comment: Lately ,,, I created a datatable and when a user clicks on  an addrow button I transferred the data form the gridview to the datatable and then added new row to the datatable and then transferred the data form the datatable to the gridview again.
Actually I was just thinking  that the above way is not the most efficient way and I have to reduce  data transfer  between the client and the server .
So is there something  wrong  with my process?